# navigator recursive make heirarchy array

Tags: php, arrays

[image: this is table]


i want the parent with childs in array!
recursive part is make a empty array!
php:

```
function buildNavigation($items, $parent = NULL) {
    $arr = [];
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item->parent == $parent) {
            $hasChildren = true;
            $arr[] = $item->title;
            $arr[] = $item->link;

            $arr[] = $this->buildNavigation($items, $item->id);
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

result:

```
array (size=15)
0 => string 'صفحه اصلی' (length=17)
1 => string 'index' (length=5)
2 => 
array (size=0)
  empty
3 => string 'محصولات' (length=14)
4 => string 'products' (length=8)
5 => 
array (size=69)
  0 => string 'ابزار' (length=10)
  1 => string 'cornic' (length=6)
  2 => 
    array (size=0)
      empty

12 => string 'تمام صفحات' (length=19)
13 => string '' (length=0)
14 => 
array (size=0)
  empty
```

> array (size=0)
>         empty

how can remove this empty array from all?
thanks for help! 
how should remove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add it to array, if it's empty.

```
$navigation = $this->buildNavigation($items, $item->id);
if(!empty($navigation)){
    $arr[] = $navigation;
}
```